# Widgets aligned vertically and horizontally

Tags: android

I would like to create a layout which would pretty be like in the image down below but I don't really know what Layout pattern should I use to achive that.I know how can I align widgets horizontally and vertically too but don't know how can I align widgets vertically and horizontally in same time. As you can see in image below there is one column of `TextView`'s and one column of `EditText`'s and on each row `TextView` is aligned with `EditText` widget which I know how to align but as you can see `TextView`'s are also aligned vertically and `EditText`'s as well which I don't know how to achieve this without losing either vertical alignment or horizontal alignment.

[image: Layout]

Comment: Use TableLayout ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Label Goes Here:"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="#fff"

                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Label Goes Here:"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="#fff"

                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ah that's what I tried but I didn't specify a custom width for widgets, ty.

Comment: If this helped you, please mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the Grid Layout system from the Android Development Resources.  I use this in my own project, as well I use the grid system on really any other front end UI I'm working on whether it be mobile, or an Angular project.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout

Here is a wonderful tutorial/explanation:

https://blog.stylingandroid.com/gridlayout-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve that layout without nesting layouts and for better control is to use `ConstraintLayout`.

In a ConstraintLayout, every View can have it's top/bottom/left/right sides constrained to either another View or it's parent.

So for a short example:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First Name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Last Name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/firstName"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/firstName"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/firstName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstNameEdit"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/firstName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/firstName"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/firstName"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lastNameEdit"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/lastName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/lastName"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/lastName"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note that I did not add in any of the margins, since that's something you would know how to do with any layout.

But take a look at what I did with the constraints.

First, I told the layout that I wanted the FirstName TextView to be placed to the top left of the `parent` which is the Layout itself.

Next, I told the layout that I wanted the LastName TextView to be placed below the FirstName TextView *and* to have it's left and right sides be the same as the FirstName TextView.

Afterwards, I told the layout that I wanted the FirstName EditText to be placed to the right of the FirstName TextView. However, I wanted it to stretch to fill up the rest of the screen by placing the width to be 0dp and the right constraint to be `parent`. Finally, I told it to restrain it's top and bottom to be the same as the FirstName TextView.

I repeated the same with the LastName EditText.

You can continue doing the same with the other views and create the exact layout you want just by properly telling the layout where you want the views to be placed.

The benefits of using this is so you don't create nested layouts and it adjusts well across different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:weightSum="10"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Label Goes Here:"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#fff"

            />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```